# Problem saving regstration form data to sqlite database (App closed immediately)

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm extremely beginner to android development, I'm making a simple app that has a registration form, but after the fields filled with data and when the save button pressed the app closed immediately.
I've included the code because I don't know where's the faulty part:

```
        public void AddNew(View v)
    {
        if(Image_path.isEmpty())
        {
            Toast.makeText(this,"please choose a profile picture",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        EditText ed_full_name = findViewById(R.id.full_name);
        EditText ed_mobie = findViewById(R.id.phone);
        EditText ed_id_num = findViewById(R.id.id_num);
        EditText ed_address = findViewById(R.id.address);
        EditText ed_section_id = findViewById(R.id.straction_id);
        EditText ed_card_id = findViewById(R.id.card_id);
        EditText ed_dis_id = findViewById(R.id.dis_id);
        String full_name = ed_full_name.getText().toString();
        String mobile = ed_mobie.getText().toString();
        String id_num = ed_id_num.getText().toString();
        String address = ed_address.getText().toString();
        String card_id = ed_card_id.getText().toString();
        String section_id = ed_section_id.getText().toString();
        String dis_id = ed_dis_id.getText().toString();
        if(full_name.isEmpty() || mobile.isEmpty() || id_num.isEmpty() || address.isEmpty() || card_id.isEmpty() || section_id.isEmpty())
        {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Please fill all fields",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        DBHelper mHelper = new DBHelper(this);
        SQLiteDatabase db = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("full_name", full_name);
        values.put("mobile", mobile);
        values.put("id_num", id_num);
        values.put("address", address);
         values.put("section_id", section_id);
        values.put("card_id", card_id);
        values.put("image_path", Image_path);
        values.put("dis_id", dis_id);
        db.insertWithOnConflict("Clients",
                null,
                values,
                SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
        db.close();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Saved successfully! ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
```

Comment: Can you show the stacktrace logcat?

Answer (score 0):

You are calling finish(); on your Activity, that will cause it to close. If it is the only Activity on your App's backstack, the App will also close.

Comment: I did that, resulting the same.